# Static class and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I'm trying to create 2 class with the same methods name.
Its an exercise, so i cant change the behavior.

Person.h

```
#ifndef __PERSON__
#define __PERSON__
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class person{
protected:
  string name;
  static int quantity;
private:

public:
  person();
  ~person();
  string getName() const;

  static void add();
  static int getQuantity();

};
#endif
```

person.cpp

```
#include "person.h"

int person::quantity=0;
person::person(){}
person::~person(){}
string person::getName() const{
  return this->name;
}


int person::getQuantity(){
  return person::quantity;
}
```

user.h

```
#ifndef __USER__
#define __USER__
#include <iostream>
#include "person.cpp"

using namespace std;


class user:public person{
private:
  int age;
  static int quantity;

public:
  user();
  ~user();

  static int getQuantity();
  static void add();

  int getAge();
  void setAge(int age);


};            
#endif
```

user.cpp

```
#include "user.h"

int user::quantity=0;

user::user():person(){}
user::~user(){}

int user::getQuantity(){
  return user::quantity;
}
void user::add(){
  user::quantity++;
}
int user::getAge(){
  return this->age;
}
void user::setAge(int age){
  if(age>=0)this->age=age;
}
```

the problem is ld: duplicate symbol person::getQuantity()      in /var/folders/bg/171jl37d05v69c4t6t1tt03m0000gn/T//ccRJU6B9.o and /var/folders/bg/171jl37d05v69c4t6t1tt03m0000gn/T//ccVVSd1i.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

but i create the static methods for that specific class. How can i solve that?

Comment: Identifiers that contain double underscores are reserved for the implementation. That applies to macro names as well.

Comment: `using namespace std;` in headers is bad form too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... the problem was the #include "person.cpp"

Answer (score 3):

You

```
#include "person.cpp"
```

which is wrong. It will get compiled twice.

You probably want to `#include "person.h"`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are including person.cpp in the beginning of user.h. This causes the contents of person.cpp to be compiled twice, so no you have two definitions of all members of the class. You probably meant to include person.h

Answer (score 0):

You are including `#include "person.cpp"` in `User.h`.

Change this to `#include "person.h"` and everything will be fine.

I tried to compile your code in Visual Studio 2010 after making this change and everything compiled just fine.